# Given the following signalling elements design the optimum receiver?

Tags: filter-design, optimal-filter

Given the following signaling elements,
\begin{align}
g_1(t) &= A \quad \text{for} \quad -T/4 < t \leq 0 \\
g_2(t) &= A \quad \text{for} \quad  0  < t \leq T/4 \\
g_3(t) &= A \quad \text{for} \quad -T/2 < t \leq 0 \\
g_4(t) &= A \quad \text{for} \quad 0 < t \leq T/2 \\
\end{align}
I have deduce the orthonormal basis to be,
\begin{align}
\omega_1(t) &= 1 \quad \text{for} \quad -T/2 < t \leq -T/4 \\
\omega_2(t) &= 1 \quad \text{for} \quad -T/4  < t \leq 0 \\
\omega_3(t) &= 1 \quad \text{for} \quad 0 < t \leq T/4 \\
\omega_4(t) &= 1 \quad \text{for} \quad T/4 < t \leq T/2 \\
\end{align}

And finally I have the vector representation of each signaling element which is given by,
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
g_1 \\
g_2 \\
g_3 \\
g_4
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & A & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & A & 0 \\
A & A & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & A & A \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\omega_1 \\
\omega_2 \\
\omega_3 \\
\omega_4
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Giving me,
\begin{align}
v_1 &= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & A & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
&
v_2 &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & A & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\\
v_3 &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
A & A & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
&
v_4 &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & A & A \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
I am not sure how to use this information to design an optimum receiver. Should I translate the vectors into a QPSK constellation or should I change to orthonormal basis into a 2-dimensional basis?